# Three factor pairs summing to consecutive numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

The number $144$ can be factored in three different ways such that $$12\times12=9\times16=8\times18$$ with$$12+12=24;\quad 9+16=25; \quad8+18=26$$ the sum of the factor pairs being consecutive numbers,  Similarly $180$ also has three such factor pairs, $(12,15), (10,18), (9,20)$.

Is there any algorithm or way to find such numbers which have three-factor pairs? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Basically you are finding
$$k=ab=cd=fg$$
where
$$a+b+2=c+d+1=f+g$$
with $a,b,c,d,f,g,k\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: If you're familiar with programming, you could write such a program yourself. Just plug-in a few numbers which satisfy the '+' equations and then try to see if the products are nice. A computer is much faster than the brain:-))

Comment: Wow thank you so much unfortunately I lack such skill ... Any help is appreciated but thank you for the prompt responses

Comment: Are you looking specifically for factor pairs that sum to consecutive numbers?

Comment: I'm just trying to see if there is a way to generate these numbers

Comment: There are $118$ such numbers below $10^7$. The largest is $9911160$. All of them are multiples of $36$.

Comment: Wow julian you made my day thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial algorithm to give you a start.

You are looking for numbers with factors $a\cdot b = k$ such that $(1-a-b)^2-4ab = a^2+b^2-2(a+ab+b)+1$ is a perfect square. Additionally, you need $a+b-1+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2(a+ab+b)+1}$ be divisible by 2. Finally, you want $k$ to be divisible by $\dfrac{a+b-1+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2(a+ab+b)+1}}{2}$. Then, you will have found a pair factors. Extending this to a triple could follow a similar pattern. The pair would be:

Let $c = \dfrac{2k}{a+b-1+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2(a+ab+b)+1}}$

Then you have:
$c+\dfrac{a+b-1+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2(a+ab+b)+1}}{2}+1 = a+b$
and 
$c\cdot \dfrac{a+b-1+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2(a+ab+b)+1}}{2}=ab=k$

Comment: Thank you so there are infinitely many?

Comment: That is unclear. I did not do any sort of analysis on how many there may be. I just took what Karn Watcharasupat did and solved for b in the equations:

$ab=cd$
$a+b=c+d+1$

First, solve for $d$ in the first equation:
$d = \dfrac{ab}{c}$

Plug that into the second equation:
$a+b=c+\dfrac{ab}{c}+1$

Solve for $c$ in terms of $a,b$.